# How to use IE options with IWebDriver?

Tags: c#, selenium, automation

I have the following code which does exactly what I want:

```
private IWebDriver driver;
var options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
```

However, people I work with need the driver variable to be a `IWebDriver` instead:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer();
capabilities.SetCapability("ie.ensureCleanSession", true);
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(remoteAddress), capabilities, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

So I was wondering if there is a way to set the following property:

```
options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
```

using a `RemoveWebDriver`? Can I set it in `DesiredCapabilities` object?

Something like this maybe (can't find something like this):

```
capabilities.SetCapability("ie.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings ", true);
```

Or to include the `options` object in `RemoveWebDriver`?

Comment: The inheritance hierarchy goes: IWebDriver > RemoteWebDriver > InternetExplorerDriver. So by creating an InternetExplorerDriver object, you are also creating a RemoteWebDriver object, which uses the interface IWebDriver.

If you really want to create an instance of RemoteWebDriver you can pass in objects variable you created and set the path to the exe and it will use the InternetExplorerDriver.

Comment: @stewartm Thanks a lot for your answer!! I had though of this, and I did this as a try: options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
                        IWebDriver _driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);

Comment: but then I cannot set capabilities and such?

Comment: I need to also set this (this was the problem I had with this solutio): driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(remoteAddress), capabilities, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout * 10));

Comment: If you need to use both Options and Capabilities is set whatever capabilities and options you need, then add the options into the capabilities:

capabilities.SetCapability(InternetExplorerOptins.Capability, options)

Then pass in the capabilities object into the constructor

Comment: wonderful!! exactly what I needed ;) thanks!!

Comment: No problem :). Maybe just try and mark this question is resolved somehow? Although I didn't submit the answer in the answer section...

Comment: hmmm you can post your answer to have points or I can post it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to use both Options and Capabilities, you can add options into your capabilities and then pass the capabilities into the remote webdriver as a parameter.

```
capabilities.SetCapability(InternetExplorerOptions.Capability, options);
```

Comment: capabilities.SetCapability(InternetExplorerOptions.Capability, options); isn't the way to write it I just noticed, did I missed something?

Comment: it should be capabilities.SetCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings"‌​, true); I think?

Comment: I think for the most part, all of the settings in InternetExplorerOptions can be set as capabillities. It's just the task of finding what string to put in the capability, which can be hard to find :(. Check out this page: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities. It has a lot of capability strings for all the browsers